# Android Recyclerview scroll to specific item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a simple question but it doesn't seem technically easy to solve.

I have a recyclerview with plus minus 90 items and at the bottom I have a button.
The intention is that when I touch the button I want the recyclerview for example to scroll to item 67.
Each item has its own height and is therefore not identical.

Is there any way I can solve this, I'm surprised I can't find much about this.

I don't expect a solution with explanation but more a direction on where to look.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recyclerView.scrollToPosition(67)